# Interpretation of "need not"

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the meaning of "need not" in the following sentence?

> The amount withdrawn **need not** be repaid.

Does it always mean that it must not be repaid, or does it also extend to persons who may wish to repay?

I am confused as to its interpretation. In my view it gives an option to the borrower to not have to repay, whereas it could also mean that the money **should not** be repaid.

Comment: Who says it means that the money _should_ not be repaid? Where have you seen that interpretation?

Comment: This is the NPI "semi-modal" use of _need_. In a negative context, as here, _need_ works like any modal auxiliary verb: _It can/may/must/need not be repaid_. This behavior is optional; one could also say (and most likely would) _It doesn't need to be repaid_, as if _need_ were a normal verb and not a modal auxiliary. The meaning of _need not_ is like _don't have to_, rather than _must not_; in the affirmative, _need to_ means _must_ , and so does _have to_, but their negations are different.

Answer (score 3):

Your view is correct. The implication is that it *may* be repaid, but certainly there is no need to repay.